# Git repository file size is larger after migrating to git-lfs

Tags: git-lfs

I have a fairly large repository that takes quite awhile to clone from remote. I decided I might benefit from Git LFS so I went and migrated the repo. Though, after migrating, pushing and re-cloning, the repository takes up more disk space than the original repository. The culprit on the FS is .git/lfs/objects.

Before the migration my .git folder was 846MB, after migration it was 2GB, which is counter-intuitive.

I've tried two methods of migration. One was BFG and the other was using git filter-branch (which took three days x_x). Both ended up with the same results.

Am I missing something? Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple - objects in git are compressed while objects in lfs are not.
I myself in the same situation but much worse: original .git folder was 5.7GB, after migrating it skyrocketed to 26GB.